# Progress in robustifying mathematics - i.e. making mathematical theorems robust to small changes in hypotheses

Tags: gr.group-theory, real-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, gm.general-mathematics, functional-equations

The idea of making a mathematical theorem robust to small changes in its hypotheses has been known for some time. In areas such as group theory reasonable progress has been made leading to the theory of approximate groups - see Terence Tao's comment [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/03/11/ben-green-the-polynomial-freiman-ruzsa-conjecture/#comment-89) and related [notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/approximate-groups/).

It seems that Stanislav Ulam was the first to discuss this overall concept in reference to the stability of functional equations in a talk in 1940. In his "A Collection of Mathematical Problems", Chapter 6, Section 1 "Stability" he asks "When is it true that by changing a little the hypotheses of a theorem, one can still assert that the thesis of the theorem remains true or approximately true?" He gives the following example by way of illustration:

"If $f(x)$ is a measurable real- valued function defined for all real $x$
satisfying the inequality
$|f(x + y) - (f(x)+f(y))|<e$
everywhere, one can show that there exists a function $l(x) = ax$
such that
$l(x + y) = l(x) + l(y$) and $|l(x) - f(x)| \leq e$
everywhere. We say then that the functional equation of linearity
$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$
is stable with respect to a change into an inequality."

My question is:

> What progress has been made in making appropriate parts of mathematics robust in this sense and what are the important results that have been proved in this direction?

Note that I don't mean making proofs more robust but rather asking how can we adapt or discover theorems that are robust to small changes in their hypotheses so that the theorem remains true or approximately so. (See the references above to approximate groups and Ulam's example.)

A further example would be in statistics where the assumption of normally distributed noise is very common. However in reality noise is never normally distributed and so it is very important to have theorems say about robust estimators that have desirable properties even if the gaussian assumption is not met, up to some approximation.

What I am really asking for is examples of mathematical fields where this process has occurred. Great detail is not necessarily required just a quick outline with references would be great.

Related to Sam Hopkin's answer and Will Sawin's comment is the common pattern especially in combinatorics - "if a system is not in the state S then there exists an object with property P". If we take the contrapositive we get "if there are 0 objects with property P then the system is in the state S". 0 can then be parametrised to generate more robust theorems - "if we have less then x objects with property P the system is in the state S". I gave the example of the [Sylvester-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) in my comment to Sam's answer.

Comment: Is "robustifying mathematics" really a well-known piece of terminology? I would have associated that phrase with making proofs more robust, not "showing that certain algebraically defined objects remain stable with respect to perturbations" which seems to be what you are actually asking about.

Comment: Also, what are your criteria for "importance"? I have been interested in the Banach-algebraic versions of Ulam-type stability questions for many years, but how am I meant to say which things I am interested in or have seen proved are "important"?

Comment: I believe calling such phenomena "robustifying mathematics" is overly emphatic.

Comment: @YemonChoi You could use own definition of importance and say what that is. Perhaps the term "robustifying" isn't standard terminology but my example of Ulam was trying to make it clearer. I've heard the term used quite a few times by Terence Tao for example with the same meaning as described here. In particular the example of approximate groups may be the most pertinent.

Comment: @YCor I wasn't trying to make any particularly statement but rather was just interested in the directions that professor Tao referenced in his comments and Ulam in his talk and book.

Comment: I'm afraid that I still have serious misgivings about this question in its current form, for several reasons. One is that the questions is rather vague about its premises, because the "approximate group theory" being used in (nehighbourhoods of) additive combinatorics actually has very little to do with Hyers-Rassias-Ulam stability, because the two settings use different notions of "approximately true" and "close to a true solution". So when you say "The concept of a robust or stable version of a mathematical theorem is well known" I would dispute the premise

Comment: Secondly, your question is extremely broad in scope, asking "What progress has been made in robustifying appropriate parts of mathematics". This makes it sound like "robustifying mathematics" is some agreed programme, and with all due respect to The Blogging Of Tao I don't think it is. Part of the problem is that one can ask Ulam-type stability questions about almost any metric algebraic structure and by now there are probably hundreds of papers on stability of functional equations.

Comment: Could you not narrow down your question, either by refocusing on approximate group theory (since that is what Illustrious People Do) or asking about a particular class of algebraic structures where you would like to know what Ulam-type stability results are known? I am having trouble understanding what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @YemonChoi I appreciate your comments and understand the question is vague but out of necessity as I will try to explain. The reason why I don't want to ask a very specific question only about approximate group theory is that I already know about that. What I want to know is about other areas of mathematics that I don't already know about where a similar approach has been taken - i.e. hypothesis A implies conclusion B. What happens if A is true only approximately in some sense does B then also hold approximately.

Comment: @YemonChoi It is to be expected that the notion of "approximately" will vary and this is part of the process of adapting theorems to be more robust in this sense. It's worth noting that Ulam in his book section on stability references both functional analysis and group theory as well as discrete structures, If you can access the book which I know is challenging to do it is worth looking at this section.

Comment: @YemonChoi The example of Robust Statistics given by Iosif is a good one and illustrates the importance of this type of research I believe. Having worked in computer vision I know how unrealistic the assumptions of say gaussian noise are and the theorem that gives a conclusion based on this assumption is generally made far more useful if the hypothesis is adapted to "approximate gaussian noise" (in some sense). Similarly "linear" is a great assumption for elegant theorems but "approximately linear" is much better for applications.

Comment: @YemonChoi I do thank you for your feedback though and hopefully I have assuaged some of your concerns in my response. I will also think how I can perhaps provide more guidance for the reader directly in the question itself.

Comment: I too have serious misgivings about this question — as @YemonChoi says, “robustifying” can mean different things in different areas of mathematics, and any generalisation can be said to make the theorem “robust to a change in hypothesis”. I’m voting to close.

Comment: Possibly along the lines you're seeking is **Defects of Properties in Mathematics** by Ban/Gal -- [amazon.com link](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9810249241) and [World Scientific Publishers link](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4937) and [google-scholar search for papers that mention the book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C16&q=%22Defects+of+Properties+in+Mathematics%22+Ban+Gal).

Comment: @HJRW I wouldn't get hung up on the word "robustify". Take it to mean as I define it purely for the scope of this question.  In terms of your comment about generalisation. Of course you are right that often generalising does make a theorem robust to changes in hypothesis however we are talking about something more specific where a small change in hypothesis allows one to maintain the conclusion up to a small change also. Often the change can be parametrised precisely using a metric.

Comment: @HJRW Take the generalisation of the concept of integer to algebraic number fields. We do not recover unique factorisation but only of ideals so the conclusion of our basic theorem has radically changed. Similarly for the generalisation of finite abelian groups to finite non-abelian the classification theorem is radically more complex and different.

Comment: @IvanMeir: Except that there's an opposite point of view, which is that the generalisation from $\mathbb{Z}$ to number fields taught us that ideals are more natural than elements. Phrased thus, the conclusion of the "basic theorem" didn't change at all, so your example exactly makes the point: a substantial fraction of all theorems proved could be framed as examples for your question, which makes it way too broad. (By the way, I have no idea what you mean by the "classification theorem" for finite non-abelian groups. There is no such theorem.)

Comment: @IvanMeir: By the way, I'd be happier if you said that number fields don't count because you're specifically interested in relaxing equations to inequalities. It would still be a huge question (much of my own field of geometric group theory would still provide an example, for instance), but it would go some way towards narrowing the scope.

Comment: @HJRW  OK then the classification of finite simple groups - I just meant the non-abelian part. I think you may have misunderstood me - apologies if I wasn't very clear but I was giving the examples of (classification of) abelian -> non-abelian groups and (factorisation theory of) integers ->algebraic integers as examples of generalisations that don't fit the pattern of stability/robustness in my question.

Comment: @IvanMeir: What "pattern"? To quote the question: "how can we adapt or discover theorems that are robust to changes in their hypotheses so that the theorem remains true or approximately so". Every time someone strengthens a theorem (by, for example, removing a hypothesis), it provides an example of this. But surely you can't want every example where a hypothesis has been removed from a theorem!!!???

Comment: @HJRW Not any change in their hypotheses but a small change, preferably one that can be measured to be small via some metric.  To quote Ulam again "When is it true that by changing a little the hypotheses of a theorem, one can still assert that the thesis of the theorem remains true or approximately true?". In general this will not include removing hypotheses as this is a discontinuous change that is not "small" in that sense.  Does that make sense now???!!! :-)

Comment: @HRJW I did note though that you have quoted the one place in my question that I omitted the word "small" with "changes". I've edited this now to remove this potential confusion though I am hoping the rest of the question would have made it clear. Apologies if this was the source of the confusion.

Comment: @IvanMeir: Thanks for the clarification. I still don't believe there's a well-defined question here without a clearer explanation of what constitutes a "small" change to a hypothesis. I'll leave it be now, but you'd surely get better answers with a more focussed question. Also, please edit the tags, which seem completely random.

Comment: IvanMeir: I am a bit too busy to engage right now, but thank you for the efforts to explain. I still feel that the question is **founded on a false premise and is too broad**, because Ulam stability for groups has almost nothing to do with approximate group theory as pioneered by the combinatorists: the former is a kind of worst case measure and the latter is more like an L^1-measure. I have not read Ulam's original book but I have worked seriously on Ulam-stability for Banach algebras which, upon taking the $L^1$-group algebra, is very closely related to Ulam stability for groups.

Comment: I would be much happier if you asked a question about Ulam stability for groups or other algebraic structures (in the presence of a metric). Also, why not leave comments on the answers below to help the answerers and other readers work out what you are looking for? I do not think MO should be used for collecting encyclopaedic information.

Comment: One final thought for now: in one of your replies to @HJRW you say "Not any change in their hypotheses but a small change, preferably one that can be measured to be small via some metric." But as I understand it, this is **not what happens in approximate group theory** in the sense of the work+blogging you refer to! They are concerned with subsets of groups where a large proportion of the elements satisfy subgroup-like behaviour: like I said, an average statement, rather than a "supremum of error over all local tests is small" condition which is what Ulam stability is understood as

Comment: @YemonChoi Of course I realise that approximate group theory does not use a metric in this way I was meaning more a numerical measure like % of points. The reason why I haven't left comments on the answers was I don't have a lot of time and replying to your comments and others and updating my question accordingly has occupied me entirely. If you want to ask a more specific question about Ulam stability for groups or other algebraic structures please be my guest but as I said before that is not what I want to do. I'm more interested as I said before in the broader scope.

Comment: @YemonChoi Perhaps you would consider adding an answer based on your knowledge of Ulam Stability for Banach algebras though? I'd also be interested in the relation to the group question you mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

There is a direction of research in statistics called [robust statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics).

There also is a direction of research in probability, initiated by Zolotarev, concerned with [stability problems in probability theory](https://www.google.com/search?q=zolotarev%20stability%20ideal%20metrics&oq=zolotarev%20stability%20ideal%20metrics&aqs=chrome..69i57.23168j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). There is also [The International Seminar on Stability Problems for Stochastic Models](http://www.ipiran.ru/conference/stabil_eng/), founded by Zolotarev.

Comment: Related, though not exactly the same, is the topic of [robust optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_optimization).

Comment: @TimothyChow : Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is common in extremal combinatorics. Quoting page 17 of the current draft of Yufei Zhao's "Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics" textbook (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ashj34jk6i905n/AAAhThbmPXvJcYOHS0IU2cQJa/gtacbook.pdf):

> It turns out there is a general phenomenon in combinatorics where once some density crosses an existence threshold (e.g., the Turán density is the threshold for -freeness), it will be possible to find not just one copy of the desired object, but in fact lots and lots of copies. This principle is usually called **supersaturation**. It is a fundamental idea useful for many applications, including in our upcoming determination of () for general .

Similarly, it often happens that when there is a unique extremal example for some combinatorial problem, you can also show that if you have an object which is "nearly" extremal, it has to be "close" to this unique example in some sense.

Comment: Technically I suppose the first kind of phenomenon ("supersaturation") is about strengthening the conclusion rather than weakening the hypothesis; but the second phenomenon (which I think is often just called "robustness" in this context) is definitely about weakening the hypothesis.

Comment: Probably one can rescue a lot of supersaturation examples by rephrasing the statement to its contrapositive. "If no such objects exist then..." becomes "If few such objects exist then..."

Comment: Yes certainly contrapositive converts stronger conclusion to weaker hypothesis.

Comment: Small correction: the second phenomenon goes under the name "stability result."

Comment: @WillSawin Yes I think this is a source of many examples. A concrete example of such a theorem being made more robust is "if there are no lines containing only 2 points from n points in the plane the points are collinear" (Sylvester-Gallai Theorem) has been progressively transformed into "if there are less than n/2 lines containing only 2 points from n points in the plane the points are collinear" (theorem of Green and Tao).

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks that is a great observation. I've made a note about this general pattern of examples in my question. I wanted to note that In Ramsey theory there are some direct examples like Szemeredi's Theorem where the hypothesis required to guarantee the existence of arithmetic progressions of a given length has been systematically weakened by lowering the upper density parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a negative example but I think it's worth mentioning.  You might think that if you were to find a counterexample to the Riemann Hypothesis, you could collect $1 million from the Clay Mathematics Institute.  This is not necessarily the case. Rule 5(c)(ii) of the [official rules](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/millennium_prize_rules_0.pdf) says:

> If …  the  counterexample  shows  that  the  original  Problem  survives
> after  reformulation  or  elimination  of  some  special  case,  then  CMI  may  recommend  that  a  small  prize,  of  an  amount  to  be  determined  by  CMI  in  its  sole  discretion,  be  awarded  to  the  author.

The above rule applies not just to the Riemann Hypothesis, but to the Hodge Conjecture, the Birch–Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture, and Yang–Mills and Mass Gap.  Evidently, there is lacking a "robust version" of these conjectures that would eliminate the need for the above escape clause.

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what this answer has to do with "robustness" as discussed by the OP.

Comment: @Wojowu If the scenario in the rule comes true, then the modified version of RH would (presumably) *not* be robust to a small modification (a strengthening) of the hypotheses.

Comment: The modifications I imagine for RH I imagine would be of the form "$\zeta$ has only finitely many zeros" or "the real parts are bounded by a constant $<1$". I'm not even sure what kind of hypotheses (in the sense of assumptions in the result) there are to speak about here.