# Oscillation functions and similar constructs

Tags: real-analysis, lo.logic

For given $f$ from reals to reals, the associated [oscillation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)) is defined as follows:

$$\textstyle
osc_f(x):= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\sup_{y \in B(x, \frac{1}{2^n}) } f(y)-\inf_{z \in B(x, \frac{1}{2^n}) } f(z) ]  
$$

Intuitively speaking, if $f$ is discontinuous at $x$, $osc_f(x)$ measures 'how big' the gap in the graph is.
The function $osc_f$ harks back to the days of Riemann, Hankel, and Ascoli.  One great advantage is that, given $osc_f$, the formula

*$f$ is continuous at $x$*

is equivalent to $osc_f(x)=0$, where the latter is much simpler (from a logical pov).

My question is whether similar constructs are found in the literature (I could not find any, but they may be known by another name).  For instance, let $B_n(f, x)$ be the $n$-th Bernstein polynomial for $f$ at $x$.  Define the *deviation* of $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ at $x$ as follows:

$$\textstyle
dev_f(x):= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\sup_{y \in B(x, \frac{1}{2^n}) } |f(y)-\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} B_m(f, y) | ]  
$$
Intuitively speaking, if $f(x)$ does not equal its Bernstein approximation $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} B_m(f, x)$, then $dev_f(x)$ measures 'how much' the deviation between the two is.  Perhaps one defines error terms in a similar way?

Comment: Somewhat related is [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/413364/15780), and perhaps more directly related is my comment there: "Possibly along the lines you're seeking is **Defects of Properties in Mathematics** by Ban/Gal -- [amazon.com link](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9810249241) and [World Scientific Publishers link](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4937#t=aboutBook) and [google-scholar search for papers that mention the book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Defects+of+Properties+in+Mathematics%22+Ban+Gal)." (some involve Bernstein polynomials)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro The "defects" book is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Oscillation and related quantities arise in harmonic analysis among other places e.g., probability and ergodic theory. The buzz words to look for are variational and jump inequalities; see [this paper](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Easeeger/papers/jsw.pdf). Also, look for jump functions and variation operators. The foundational result for these is known as Lepingle's inequality. Here is [an excellent recent survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.01309) which should provide an abundance of references.